# Typed/Racket: given Natural number defined type need multiply two numbers function to created

Tags: racket, typed-racket, church-encoding

Given the following defined structures and type need to write multiply two numbers function.  Having trouble to do that.  Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

```
(define-struct Zero ())

(define-struct Succ
  ([n : Nat]))

(define-type Nat (U Zero Succ))

(: one Nat)
(define one (Succ (Zero)))
(: two Nat)
(define two (Succ one))

( : sub-nat : Nat Nat -> Nat)
   (define (sub-nat a y)
     (cond
       [(Zero? a) a]
       [(eq? one y)
          (- a y)]))

( : add-nat ( -> Nat Nat Nat))
(define (add-nat a b)
  (cond
    [(Zero? a) b]
    ((Zero? b) a)
    [else (add-nat (Succ-n a) (Succ b))]))

( : multiply-nat : Number Nat -> Nat)
(define (multiply-nat a b)
 (cond
   [(Zero? a) a]
   [(Zero? b) b]
    [else
     (add-nat b (multiply-nat (sub-nat a one) b))]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `sub-nat` implementation is incorrect and will not type-check. While you can fix that, semantically it's more correct to just use `Succ-n` in your `multiply-nat` (just as you do for `add-nat`), since `Succ-n` is the Church numeral equivalent of `sub1`. Here's a corrected (and tested) version of `multiply-nat`:

```
(define (multiply-nat a b)
 (cond
   [(Zero? a) a]
   [(Zero? b) b]
   [else
    (add-nat b (multiply-nat (Succ-n a) b))]))
```

For testing purposes, I also wrote a `nat->number` function for converting the Church numerals to actual numerals:

```
(: nat->number : Nat -> Nonnegative-Integer)
(define (nat->number n)
  (if (Zero? n)
      0
      (add1 (nat->number (Succ-n n)))))
```

Comment: The issue isn't with the base cases, since they still will be zero in those branchs. It looks like the problem is closer to being in the use of `sub-nat`, since that's the only thing that's actually different between your version (using `(Succ-n a)`) and the original (using `(sub-nat a one)`).

Comment: @AlexKnauth Having reread the OP's case, I see their base cases would have worked too. Yes, their implementation of `sub-nat` is busted and won't type-check, and since `add-nat` already uses `Succ-n`, `multiply-nat` should use it too.

Comment: Should you edit this to specify that it's `sub-nat` that's wrong, and leave the base cases alone?

Comment: @Lyudmila Glad to be of help. You can click on the big tick next to the up/down vote arrows to tell the site the problem is solved.